# Search for scheduled script instance by parameters passed to it

Tags: netsuite

I want to search for a scheduled script or a map/reduce instance based on the parameters passed to it.

As in

```
search.create({
   type: "scheduledscriptinstance",
   filters: {
     // What do I put here?
   }
})
```

My goal is to stop an actively executing script if one exists for a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [NS Records Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/script/record/scheduledscript.html), Script Deployment Parameters aren't accessible via search joins, filters, or columns for the following record internal ids:  scheduledscript, scheduledscriptinstance, scriptdeployment, and mapreducescript.  I confirmed through the NS UI even if "store value" is selected for the parameter on the Script record, that there is no System Notes to refer to (to access previous parameter data) on either the Script or Script Deployment record.  I think as a work around you can (from the triggering or receiving scripts) log the desired parameters.  Then search the logs for the desired parameters.

```
//log parameter from receiving/triggered script
var script = runtime.getCurrentScript();
var paramName = 'custscript_paramName';
var paramValue = script.getParameter({name: paramName});
log.audit(paramName, paramValue);

//search for pertainent logs
var scriptexecutionlogSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "scriptexecutionlog",
   filters:[
      ["script.scripttype","anyof","SCHEDULED","MAPREDUCE"], 
      "AND", 
      ["title","is", "custscript_paramName"] //paramName
   ],
   columns:[
      search.createColumn({name: "internalid", join: "script", label: "Script Internal ID"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "scripttype", label: "Script Type"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "name", join: "script", label: "Name"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "internalid", label: "Internal ID"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "type", label: "Type"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "date", label: "Date"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "time", label: "Time"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "title", label: "Title"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "detail", label: "Details"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "user", label: "User"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "view", label: "View"})
   ]
});
var searchResultCount = scriptexecutionlogSearchObj.runPaged().count;
scriptexecutionlogSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
   // .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results
   //Do Something
   return true;
});
```

Comment: I thought of this, but really, really don't want to base logic off of logs